# Update or create multiple instances at the same time with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am making a POST request from the frontend to a DRF API. The format of the request is as such:

```
[{name: 'foo', age: 16}, {name: 'bar', age: 12}]
```

As the format implies - there are many instances sent. DRF should now take every instance and see if it already exists in the database. If it already exists the instance should be updated and if it does not exist, the instance should be created. Django has a neat little function update_or_create on the model manger.

**My question is where to implement that logic and how to access the validated instances of the post request.** Would this logic be best in the create function of the serializer? or the View?

I tried accessing `serializer.validated_data` which is an `OrderedDict` - which is quite hard to access. **Should I transform this OrderedDict into a normal dict and then query each item individually from the database?**

Answer (score 0):

you can write this method in serializer create method

```py
class AbcSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
         model=Abc

   def create(self, validated_data):
       """ """

       items = Abc.objects.filterr(name__in=[data['name']for data in validated_data]).values("name", "age")
       new_record = list()
       update_record = list()
       hash_dict = dict() 
       for data in items:
           hash_dict[data['name']] = data
       for data in validated_data:
           if data['name'] in hash_dict:
            update_record.append(data)
         else:
           new_record.append(data)
       Abc.objects.bulk_create(new_record)
       for data in update_record:
          db_data = Abc.objects.get(**data)  
          db_data.age = data['age']
          db_data.save()
```

Comment: hey, can you eventually show how you would loop over each instance?